# Using createMetadataAccountV3

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, metaplex, umi

I am trying to add metadata to my token, so I wrote the following function:

```
import {clusterApiUrl} from "@solana/web3.js";
import {createUmi} from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults";
import {createSignerFromKeypair} from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";
import {fromWeb3JsPublicKey} from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-web3js-adapters'

export async function addMetadataToToken(mintAccountPubkey, platformKeypair) {
  const chain = clusterApiUrl("devnet");
  const umi = createUmi(chain);

  const signer = createSignerFromKeypair(umi, platformKeypair);
  umi.identity = signer
  umi.payer = signer;

  const CreateMetadataAccountV3Args = {
    mint: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(mintAccountPubkey),
    mintAuthority: null,
    payer: signer,
    updateAuthority: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(platformKeypair.publicKey),
    data: {
        name: "my Token",
        symbol: "MYY",
        uri: "google.com",
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
        creators: null,
        collection: null,
        uses: null
    },
    isMutable: false,
    collectionDetails: null
  }

  let transactionBuilder = createMetadataAccountV3(umi, CreateMetadataAccountV3Args)
  let transaction = await transactionBuilder.buildAndSign(umi)
  let txHash = await umi.rpc.sendTransaction(transaction)
}
```

But I am hitting the following error:

```
Error: The provided signer is not required to sign this transaction.
```

I am using the same signer (keypair) who created the mint account - what am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried setting the mint authority to the keypair’s public key?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately didn't work.